# WPF - animation for different controls via xaml

Tags: wpf, animation

I have a listbox that is populated with a custom control.  It works fine.  Now I am looking to create this effect...

When the user hovers over an item in the listbox, I want that item to increase its shadowdepth (already showing) and all other items to decrease their shadowdepth.  Can this be done?  Can it be done in Xaml?

I have played with it but have been unsuccessful.

Here is my current listbox setup if it matters...

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Applets}" Margin="10,92,10,10" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <custom:AppletButton 
                    Margin="{Binding Path=DesiredMargin}" 
                    Width="{Binding Path=DesiredWidth}" 
                    Height="{Binding Path=DesiredHeight}"

                    CornerRadius="{Binding Path=CornerRoundness}"
                    BackgroundImage="{Binding Path=BackImage}"
                    BorderThickness="{Binding Path=BorderWidth}"

                    Text ="{Binding Path=Title}"
                    TextColor ="{Binding Path=TitleColor}"
                    AlternateText ="{Binding Path=Description}"
                    AlternateTextColor ="{Binding Path=DescriptionColor}"
                    AlternateTextShadowColor="White"
                    AlternateTextSize="56"
                    TextShadowColor="Gray"
                    CaptionTextSize="72"
                    ToolTip="{Binding Path=ToolTip}"
                    ShadowDepth="15"
                    SaturationLevel="{Binding Path=Saturation}"

                    Tag="{Binding Path=Tag}">


                    <custom:AppletButton.BorderBrush>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding BorderBrushImage}" />
                    </custom:AppletButton.BorderBrush>

                    <custom:AppletButton.BitmapEffect>
                        <DropShadowBitmapEffect x:Name="AppletShadow" ShadowDepth="5" Opacity="0.5" Softness="0.5" />
                    </custom:AppletButton.BitmapEffect>

                </custom:AppletButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

TIA

Jeff

Comment: Atleast, you should consider about converter.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First solution**

If your items fill your entire ItemsPresenter you can easily do it in pure XAML.

Copy the standard template for the ListBox and add a Border around the ItemsPresenter, which will compute the shadow depth for all non-hovered items:

```
<Border custom:AppletButton.ShadowDepth="15">
  <ItemsPresenter />
</Border>
```

Now add a trigger to the Border to change this when IsMouseOver="true":

```
<Border.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="custom:AppletButton.ShadowDepth" Value="10" />
  </Trigger>
</Border.Triggers>
```

In your ItemTemplate, use FindAncestor to bind ShadowDepth to the Border's ShadowDepth:

```
ShadowDepth="{Binding Path=custom:AppletButton.ShadowDepth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,Border,1}}"
```

Note that "Path=" is required when using attached properties.

Also in your ItemTemplate, override the FindAncestor setting whenever the mouse is over the item:

```
<custom:AppletButton.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="ShadowDepth" Value="40" />
  </Trigger>
</custom:AppletButton.Triggers>
```

Now any time the mouse is over the WrapPanel, all items will have a lower shadow depth, but if the mouse is over a given item it will have a higher shadow depth.

The down-side of this is that if the mouse is over a blank part of the WrapPanel, all items will lower their shadow depth but none will be hilighted.

**Second solution**

If you need to "de-hilight" items in the listbox *only* when the mouse is over an actual item (as opposed to over the panel), you will need to use some code.

One simple way to do this is create a "IsMouseOverAnyItem" property and use it as shown above.  For example, you could subclass WrapPanel, and in MeasureOverride create a list of objects that bind to the "IsMouseOver" properties of each panel child, something like this:

```
public class MyWrapPanel : WrapPanel
{
  List<ValueMonitor> _monitors;

  public bool IsMouseOverAnyItem { get { return (bool)GetValue(IsMouseOverAnyItemProperty); } set { SetValue(IsMouseOverAnyItemProperty, value); } }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMouseOverAnyItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsMouseOverAnyItem", typeof(bool), typeof(MyWrapPanel));


  protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  {
    if(_monitors!=null) _monitors.ForEach(monitor => monitor.Disable());
    _monitors = (
        from child in Children.OfType<object>()
        select new ValueMonitor(new Binding("IsMouseOver") { Source=child },
                                () => Update())  // ValueChangedAction 
      ).ToList();
    Update();
    return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
  }

  public void Update()
  {
    IsMouseOverAnyItem = _monitors.All(monitor => (bool)monitor.Value);
  }
}
```

The above assumes you have a ValueMonitor class that can watch a binding value and notify you if it changes.  It might be implemented something like this:

```
public class ValueMonitor : DependencyObject
{
  Action _valueChangedAction;

  public object Value { get { return (object)GetValue(ValueProperty); } set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); } }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(ValueMonitor), new PropertyMetadata
  {
    PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, e) => ((ValueMonitor)obj)._valueChangedAction()
  });


  public ValueMonitor(BindingBase binding, Action valueChangedAction)
  {
    _valueChangedAction = valueChangedAction;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ValueProperty, binding);
  }

  public void Disable()
  {
    ClearValue(ValueProperty);
  }
}
```